# What does ホーム mean and why is it written in Katakana?

Tags: meaning, usage

I heard announcements in the train (Hibiya Line):

```
この電車は六本木 ホーム (or ホーメ not sure) 中目黒行きです。
```

The English version of the above:

```
This train is bound for Nakameguro via Roppongi.
```

So, does ホーム (or ホーメ) mean "via" here?
And why is ホーム used here instead of using Japanese word to mean "via" or "through"?

Comment: Homemade → ホームメード,  here ホーム means "Home" :(

Comment: ホーム is derived from the second syllable of ”Platform".  // Platform  ==> プラットホーム　==>　ホーム  //  The poster misheard 方面 as ホーム

Comment: @CraigHicks you are right, and Halfway explained it clearly

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assume you are taking the Tokyo Metro Hibiya Line.

What you are actually hearing is 「この電車は六本木方面、中目黒行きです。」

Google this phrase, and you can find youtube videos of the announcement uploaded by train enthusiasts.

「方面(ほうめん)」, pronounced "ho-men", means "direction". So, the train pulling in to the station moves in the Roppongi direction and is Nakameguro bound (as opposed to the 北千住方面, or Kitasenju direction, which would take you in the opposite direction).

Comment: you are exactly right. Sometimes these pronunciations (announcements and while Japanese people speaking) are vague to me (may be because I am beginner)

Comment: Don't worry about not being able to catch every syllable, especially the subtle ones like 「ん」. I still remember when I couldn't understand any of the announcements. You'll get there, especially with you trying so hard :)

Comment: I've never heard "方面" in the subway platform.

Comment: ^ OP wrote: "I heard announcements **in the train** ".

Answer (score 2):

”ホーム" comes from "platform." Generally there are inbound and outbound platform. In Roppongi station you can have outbound train service as "bound for Nakameguro."

Comment: 上り　のぼり　outbound  //  下り　くだり    inbound  //  I know you know, but its not obvious.

Comment: For me, Saitama is out of scope. (just kidding)

Comment: Also note the 和製英語 phrase マイホーム has a totally different meaning! OP may encounter this...